# Why ray goes down when applied a magnetic force between it in the JJ Thompson experiment?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electrons, atoms

I have a question! I was learning about JJ Thomson's Cathode Ray Tube experiment and I understand why the ray goes up when it passes through a Wien's filter, but I cannot plenty understand why it goes down when a magnet its applied by the sides.

In this picture for example when professor applies a magnetic force, the ray goes up. Does that means he is pointing the north pole towards the ray?

[image: Ray going up after magnet applied]

Now for this picture, the presenter states that when there is a magnet between the ray, it should go down. The south pole is at the other side.

[image]

I'd like to know how does that work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you understand the [Wien's filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_filter), you must know that it depends on setting an equal force in opposite directions using E and B fields perpendicular to the trajectory of the charged particles in the beam. As in your experiment there is no opposing electric field, the charged tracks will follow the [right hand rule](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-physics/chapter/magnetic-force-on-a-moving-electric-charge/) of interaction to the magnetic field :

> to determine the direction of the magnetic force on a **positive** moving charge,

[image: right hand rule]

> Right Hand Rule: Magnetic fields exert forces on moving charges. This force is one of the most basic known. The direction of the magnetic force on a moving charge is perpendicular to the plane formed by v and B and follows right hand rule–1 (RHR-1) as shown. The magnitude of the force is proportional to q, v, B, and the sine of the angle between v and B.

Figure it out from this.